# NDVI out of range

Tags: ndvi, reflectance

I have composed a mosaics of 3 images of Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Level 2 for the bands NIR and RED. According to the Landsat Surface Reflectance Product Guide each band is supposed to be multiplied pixel wise times a scaling factor of 0.0001.
As I have understood, it might occur that after such multiplication the obtained surface reflectance values may slightly surpass/exceed the commonly known upper and lower bound of the reflectance range going from 0 to 1.
Then, I calculated NDVI and the values do not strictly go from -1 to 1 but from -0.5 to 0.98.

Could this have to do with the fact that the input surface reflectance bands (NIR and RED) slightly surpass the 0 to 1 values expected for reflectance?

Does NDVI always range from -1 to 1 or it can also range within the values -1 to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first multiply every layer by 0.0001 and then calculate NDVI the surpassing shouldn't happen, as you are dividing a *subtraction* of two positive numbers (band values) by the *addition* of the same two numbers; this is because it is a *normalized* index, which *mathematically* means that it will range from -1 to 1 in this case; as you state, your values range from -0.5 to 0.98, this lays withing the range; *surpassing* the range would be, e.g. -1.02 to 1.04